# Raspberry Pi - Errors downloading Python Modules

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to download a module for python on my raspberry pi 3. The first error I received was saying my urllib3 was not up to date. This error was given whenever I ran the pip command. So I re-installed urllib3, and it downloaded the same version I had, even though I had just ran sudo apt-get update. I then decided to remove pip, and re-install, and that didn't fix it. The final thing I have tried doing it manually downloading urllib3 from github, and then installing it onto my pi using setup.py. This was successful in eliminating the previous error, but I am now receiving this.

```
$ pip install imutils
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.5.6', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 356, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2476, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2190, in load
    ['__name__'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 74, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/vcs/mercurial.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.download import path_to_url
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 22, in <module>
    import requests, six
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
    major, minor, patch = urllib3_version
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

I would really appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: try `pip3 install urllib3`

Comment: Maybe there are two python versions running, python (2.7?) and python3 (3.4? 3.5?). Then you could try using `pip3 install ...`. In my opinion (although this might be not very helpful, sorry), playing / messing around with pip is very risky... As soon as you start doing things manually, hings might work or they might not. Probably, there is a much simpler solution coming along from another smart guy, but if not, I would recommend to re-install your complete python stuff from scratch.